# Laravel: how to establish a relationship between user_id and created_by column

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.4

I have two tables `users` which is default Laravel Auth table which has `user_id` column (not default `id` column), and second is `branch` table which I have created.

My branch table has a column `created_by` which stores the logged in user id when a new branch is created.

Now, on the front-end I am showing branch details in which I want to show the name of the user who created it. But in my branch table I have user_id in the `created_by` column.

I can get branch details simply by `Branch::find($id)` but it returns me the user_id who created it where as I want there name to appear there.

is it achievable via Eloquent ORM relationships or I need to write the whole query etc.

Please advise?

Comment: to get info who created try this package https://github.com/fico7489/laravel-revisionable-upgrade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would add the following method to your Branch model:

```
public function createdBy()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'created_by', 'user_id')
}
```

Just need to information eloquent what the foreign key is, in this case, 'created_by'. Keep in mind you can name the method differently if you like, creator() or owner(), for example.

Comment: you can either call the method directly or you can add it to the $appends array like 'protected $appends = ['createdBy'];. That way it would be accessible like $branch->created_by

Comment: Do you know how I can order by the results using the user name of the creator() ? I don't know how to do that. I have `$this->bladeVar['branches'] = Branch::orderBy($sort, $dir)->paginate(20);` this code.

Comment: Try `DB::table('branch')->orderBy($sort, $dir)->paginate(20);`

Comment: But we need to order it by the creator's name which is stored in the Users table. For that we added that function in the model. Ho we can order in that situation?

Comment: What are you passing in for `$sort`? I think you can just do `orderBy('branch.creator', $dir)`

Comment: but in `branch.creator` we are gettin the reference of the user records, and I want to sort the data using the `branch.creator->name` something like this? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Add the belongsTo relation in your Model. You need the third argument because your key is not `id`.

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Branch', 'created_by', 'user_id');
}
```

Link to documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#updating-belongs-to-relationships